# MS Graph Api is not returning all user information such as mobile phones ,office phones

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to get all user information such as DisplayName ,Office ,Manager name ,Office Phones etc.

But for few users ,its not returning Mobile Phone and Office Phone information.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace MSGraphAPI
{
    class Program
    {


        private static string clientId = "XXXXXXXXXX";


        private static string tenantID = "XXXXX";


        private static string objectId = "XXXXX";


        private static string clientSecret = "XXXX";

        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {




            //     IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            //.Create(clientId)
            //.WithTenantId(tenantID)
            //.WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            //.Build();

            //        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            //        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            //        var users = await graphClient.Users
            //            .Request()
            //            .GetAsync();

            int Flag = 0;
            var tenantId = "XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com";

            // The client ID of the app registered in Azure AD
            var clientId = "XXXX";

            // *Never* include client secrets in source code!
            var clientSecret = "XXXXX"; // Or some other secure place.

            // The app registration should be configured to require access to permissions
            // sufficient for the Microsoft Graph API calls the app will be making, and
            // those permissions should be granted by a tenant administrator.
             var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };


            // Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
            var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            // Build the Microsoft Graph client. As the authentication provider, set an async lambda
            // which uses the MSAL client to obtain an app-only access token to Microsoft Graph,
            // and inserts this access token in the Authorization header of each API request. 
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {

        // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
        var authResult = await confidentialClient
            .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();

        // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                })
                );

            // Make a Microsoft Graph API query
            var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();


            // var groups = await graphServiceClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync();

            //   IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage userss = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();




            do
            {
                        foreach (User user in users)
                        {




                            Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
                            Console.WriteLine(user.BusinessPhones);
                            Console.WriteLine(user.MobilePhone);



                           // Console.WriteLine($"{user.Id}");
                            Flag++;
                        }
                    }
                    while (users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);

                    Console.WriteLine("------");


            Console.WriteLine(Flag);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried below scope:

var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All"};

But, this throws an exception :

MsalServiceException: AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All is not valid.
Trace ID: XXXX-c578-42af-8bd2-7ddd54ee9201

I cross checked in Azure Active Directory Portal,all users are configured with Business Phones and Mobile Phones.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all your `scope` deceleration is not correct. `Microsoft Graph` doesn't support multiple `scope` assignment as you trying to
>   assign as list of string which also not in right format. Additionally
>   not `scopes` it would be `scope`

In `C#` array of string usually declare as `List<string>`

You could try following code snippet which work fine as expected.

```
    //Token Request End Point
    string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

    //I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recommended
    tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
        ["client_id"] = "b6695c7be-a695-4aea-ad87-e6921e61f659",
        ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0Nf_Your_Secret_Yp8ns4sc=",
        ["scope"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" 
    });

    dynamic json;
    AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

    json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);


    //New Block For Accessing Data from Microsoft Graph Rest API
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"));
    //Passing Token For this Request
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    //Get User List With Business Phones and Mobile Phones
    dynamic objGpraphUserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

***Class Used:***

```
 public class AccessTokenClass
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
```

I got this response See the screenshot below:

[image]

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have accepted , But please help me with getting all users . It only shows 100 users.  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999 provides 999 user beyond that i am not able to get ,there are around 5000 users which is exptected.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API returns the user in a pagination format so to get the next list of users you will have to query the url which is mentioned in **@odata.nextLink** of your current response and that will give you next set of users.

To achieve this you can run a for loop till the time **@odata.nextLink** returns **NULL** value.

Update:

1. Queried graph api to fetch users
   [image: Fetching users]
2. Queried graph api with "@odata.nextLink" to get next set of users.
   [image: Fetching users with nextLink]

Comment: So , you mean when i am making this request i.e HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users")); so ,in the next loop i should pass  @odata.nextLink to HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format(@odata.nextLink)); ?

Comment: Yes correct. I have updated my comment above with screenshots as I was not able to add the screenshots here. Please check that. Let me know if this is not clear.